# Rebinding do notation for indexed monads

Tags: haskell

I was following Conor McBride's "Kleisli arrows of outrageous fortune" paper and I've posted my implementation of his code [here](https://github.com/Gabriel439/Haskell-IMonad-Library).  Briefly, he defines the following types and classes:

```
type a :-> b = forall i . a i -> b i

class IFunctor f where imap :: (a :-> b) -> (f a :-> f b)

class (IFunctor m) => IMonad m where
    skip :: a :-> m a
    bind :: (a :-> m b) -> (m a :-> m b)

data (a := i) j where
    V :: a -> (a := i) i
```

Then he defines two types of binds, the latter of which uses `(:=)` to restrict the initial index:

```
-- Conor McBride's "demonic bind"
(?>=) :: (IMonad m) => m a i -> (a :-> m b) -> m b i
(?>=) = flip bind

-- Conor McBride's "angelic bind"   
(>>=) :: (IMonad m) => m (a := j) i -> (a -> m b j) -> m b i
m >>= f = bind (\(V a) -> f a) m
```

The latter bind works perfectly fine for rebinding `do` notation to use indexed monads with the `RebindableSyntax` extension, using the following corresponding definitions for `return` and `fail`:

```
return :: (IMonad m) => a -> m (a := i) i
return = skip . V

fail :: String -> m a i
fail = error
```

... but the problem is that I cannot get the former bind (i.e. `(?>=)`) to work.  I tried instead defining `(>>=)` and `return` to be:

```
(>>=) :: (IMonad m) => m a i -> (a :-> m b) -> m b i
(>>=) = (?>=)

return :: (IMonad m) => a :-> m a
return = skip
```

Then I created a data type guaranteed to inhabit a specific index:

```
data Unit a where
    Unit :: Unit ()
```

But when I try to rebind `do` notation using the new definitions for `(>>=)` and `return`, it does not work, as demonstrated in the following example:

```
-- Without do notation
test1 = skip Unit >>= \Unit -> skip Unit

-- With do notation
test2 = do
    Unit <- skip Unit
    skip Unit
```

`test1` type-checks, but `test2` does not, which is weird, since I thought all that `RebindableSyntax` did was let `do` notation desugar `test2` to `test1`, so if `test1` type-checks, then why does not `test2`?  The error I get is:

```
Couldn't match expected type `t0 -> t1'
            with actual type `a0 :-> m0 b0'
Expected type: m0 a0 i0 -> (t0 -> t1) -> m Unit ()
  Actual type: m0 a0 i0 -> (a0 :-> m0 b0) -> m0 b0 i0
In a stmt of a 'do' block: Unit <- skip Unit
In the expression:
  do { Unit <- skip Unit;
       skip Unit }
```

The error remains even when I use the explicit `forall` syntax instead of the `:->` type operator.

Now, I know there is another problem with using the "demonic bind", which is that you can't define `(>>)`, but I still wanted to see how far I could go with it.  Can anybody explain why I cannot get GHC to desugar the "demonic bind", even when it would normally type-check?

Comment: Since this came up in a [newer duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33488322/ranknpolymorphism-and-kleisli-arrows-of-outrageous-fortune), I'll point out that nowadays GHC (currently 7.10.2) hardly supports `ImpredicativeTypes` at all, so a lot more than `do` notation breaks for this code now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IIUC, the GHC desugarer actually runs *after* the typechecker ([source](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/HscMain)). That explains why the situation you observe is theoretically possible. The typechecker probably has some special typing rules for the do-notation, and those may be inconsistent with what the typechecker would do with the desugarred code.

Of course, it's reasonable to expect them to be consistent, so I would recommend filing a GHC bug.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I will check this out.  If they agree that's the reason for the type error I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I'm also keen to know what's going on. I faced the same issue, but was less agitated. I expect the demonic polymorphism was unexpected: it's surprised lots of people.