# RankNpolymorphism and kleisli arrows of outrageous fortune

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

I dont understand why the definition of demonbind1 yields some compiler errors. it looks like a stupid flip but somehow..

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, ScopedTypeVariables, TypeOperators, TypeFamilies,ImpredicativeTypes   #-}

type a :-> b = forall i . a i -> b i

class IFunctor f where imap :: (a :-> b) -> (f a :-> f b)

class (IFunctor m) => IMonad m where
    skip :: a :-> m a
    bind :: (a :-> m b) -> (m a :-> m b)


-- Conor McBride's "demonic bind"
(?>=) :: forall m a b i. (IFunctor m, IMonad m) => m a i -> (a :-> m b) -> m b i
(?>=) =  
  let
    -- OK 
    demonbind0 = flip (bind :: forall i. (forall j. a j -> m b j)  -> m a i -> m b i ) 
    -- KO - see error below
    demonbind1 = flip  bind :: forall i. m a i -> (forall j. a j -> m b j)  ->  m b i

    -- So i have to write this
    demonbind2 :: forall i. (m a i ->  (a :-> m b)  ->  m b i )
    demonbind2 mai ti = (bind ti) mai 
  in demonbind2
```

The error is

```
Couldn't match type ‘a j0 -> m b j0’ …
              with ‘forall i2. a i2 -> m b i2’
    Expected type: (a j0 -> m b j0) -> m a i1 -> m b i1
      Actual type: a :-> m b -> m a i1 -> m b i1
 In the first argument of ‘flip’, namely ‘bind’
    In the expression:
        flip bind :: forall i. m a i -> (forall j. a j -> m b j) -> m b i
```

Comment: its a duplicate, sorry..

Comment: Actually, it is not *quite* a duplicate. In the original question the only thing that wasn't working was `do` notation. But nowadays, GHC's `ImpredicativeTypes` extension almost doesn't work at all, so *everything* in the code breaks. Even with your `demonbind2` definition, I think you will find it very hard to *use* `(?>=)`.

Comment: true, not really a duplicate. I'll go on with manual expansion. That's really a minor harm. what is annoying on the moment is that you'd *expect* such simple operation to work out of the box.

Comment: Nope, I wouldn't call it a duplicate either. Reopened.

Answer (score 3):

Somewhat surprisingly, `ImpredicativeTypes` seem less broken than usual on the development snapshot of GHC 8.0! This compiles without errors:

```
(?>=) :: (IFunctor m, IMonad m) => m a i -> (a :-> m b) -> m b i
(?>=) = flip bind
```

I wonder what change fixed the problem.

Comment: That's surprising and also, I think, mostly not the case. I remember someone mentioning some new `ImpredicativeTypes` brokenness. Richard Eisenberg, who's made some major changes to the type system recently, responded that he'd made no effort whatsoever to avoid further breakage to that already-broken extension.

Comment: @dfeuer I didn't say that `ImpredicativeTypes` work now. I've only said that they *seem* *less broken*, and that's a completely different statement. They surely shouldn't be used until they get a proper fix.

Comment: On a positive note, there appears to be some work happening towards making them work: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/raw-attachment/wiki/ImpredicativePolymorphism/Impredicative-2015/impredicativity.pdf